# Почему в слове "брезжущий" пишется суффикс УЩ?

Tags: суффиксы

Почему "брезжущий" является исключением? Кстати, в нем уже пытаются писать суффикс АЩ (программа "правописание" при наборе текста подчеркивает это слово).

Большое спасибо за информацию.

1. Форма мн. числа как-то редко встречается, реально приходится выбирать: брезжет – брезжущий (1), брезжит – брезжащий (2) и брезжит – брезжущий (1-2).
2. А какой глагол правильнее по форме и по смыслу? Глагол «брезжить» происходит от брезг – рассвет. Родственники: березовый, белый, блеск.  Похоже: свет – светить (=испускать свет) и  брезг – брезжить. С другой стороны, «брезжить» – это, скорее, «светиться», и тогда суффикс Е в непереходном глаголе, да еще при чередованиях вида  Г/Ж обычно пишется ЕТ (брызгать – брызжет).
3. Глагол «брезжать» – современный дребезжать (вбребезги, дребедень), дальние родственники: треск, трещать.

"Брезжать" - это, конечно, не к Вам, вы вполне определенно высказались по этому вопросу.
Мне кажется, что лучше бы вернуться к исторической форме: брезжеть, брезжет, брезжущий.Или считать глагол исключением по спряжению: брезжить, но: брезжет, брезжущий.
Или всё лучше, только бы не видеть "брезжащий".

1. Еще раз большое спасибо за информацию и обсуждение. Хотя вопросов здесь больше, чем ответов, но это, скорее, положительный момент. Не решенные до конца проблемы  всегда вызывают больший интерес, чем однозначные,
2. ДОПОЛНИТЕЛЬНЫЕ ВОПРОСЫ. Интересно, как глагол  «брезжить» вписывается в современную грамматику. К какому классу он относился до изменения Лопатина «брезжущий → брезжащий», кто его ближайшие соседи? И к какому классу-группе он теперь относится? Также в каком официальном документе  и когда этот переход закреплен? 
   Это важная информация. Не каждый пользователь языка может (и должен) разбираться в исторической грамматике, но он имеет право знать причину изменений  в самых общих и понятных выражениях. Это важно и для школ, если мы хотим воспитывать думающее поколение.

Comment: Если вопрос мне, то "брезжать" я не рассматриваю вовсе. 
Он далек по смыслу.  
Речь шла о том, что глагол "брезжить" исторически спрягался по первому спряжению. Брезжить-брежет-брезжут-брезжущий.

Comment: Не брезжить, а брезгти,брезжить - на -ить, 4 класс, не мог спрягаться по 1, только по второму. А вот 1-3 классы - по 1.Брезгти - 1 класс, основа на согласный.

Comment: Всё бы ничего, да этот глагол включён в тестовые задания ЕГЭ. Зачем? Учёные ещё спорят по определению спряжения БРЕЗЖИТЬ, что хотят от детей! Даю адрес теста, в котором 11 задание с этим глаголом:https://союзженскихсил.рф/communication/forums/forming/dlya-shkolnikov-slozhnyy-variant-ege-po-russkomu-yazyku/

Answer (score 5):

А хороший вопрос оказался...

С этим глаголом "брезжить" явно что-то неординарное происходит. 
Вот как было всегда:

> Примечание 2. Глаголы хотеть, бежать, брезжить относятся к разноспрягаемым, т. е. они имеют окончания I и II спряжений. Так, глагол хотеть в единственном числе изменяется по I спряжению (хочешь, хочет), а во множественном числе - по II (хотим, хотите, хотят); глагол бежать в 3-м лице множественного числа имеет окончание -ут (бегут), в остальных -- окончания II спряжения: бежишь, бежит, бежим, бежите; глагол брезжить имеет только две формы: 3-е лицо единственного числа - брезжит (II спряжение) и 3-е лицо множественного числа - брезжут (I спряжение).

http://www.gramma.ru/RUS/?id=4.32

Все, вроде, понятно. Заодно, кстати, снимается и идея об образовании "брезжущий" от "брезжать" - поскольку и в третьем лице - "брезжут".

Но!!! 
Открываю Лопатина - "брезжат".

На вики-словарях (т.е. по Зализняку) вообще представлены две "законченных" схемы спряжения. Первая - современная с парадигмой второго спряжению: ***он брезжит, они брезжат, брезжащий***. И устаревающая, по первому: ***он брезжет, они брезжут, брезжущий***.

Мне нравится последняя формулировка. Она все объясняет. По ней получается, что непонятка с причастием брезжущий/брезжащий на самом деле - частное проявление объективно происходящего процесса смены парадигмы спряжения глагола брезжить. Когда-то бывший глаголом-исключением первого спряжения (при инфинитиве на -ить), он превращается в правильный глагол второго спряжения.

Современные же словари же и пособия отражают разную степень восприятия этого процесса.
Отсюда и вся вариативность с рекомендациями, в частности - с причастием "брезжащий/брезжущий". Но в отношении причастия думается, все-таки лучше пока писать ***брезжущий***.

Answer (score 0):

Брезжить - не от брезжать, а от брѣзждити (брезг —русск , ст.- слав. пробрѣзгъ - рассвет)-глагол с основой наст.вр. 4 класса(как ходи-(ши) от ходити, нос-(иши) от носити, смотри-(ши) отсмотрhти) ,соответствует русскому 2 спряжению.

Но в древнерусском была не только старославянская форма,но и русская- брѣзгти, глагол относился, по-моему, к 1 классу, спрягался, как современное 1 спряжение.

Но был ещё и брезгать -тоже 1 класс глагола- от брьзгъ «кислый вкус». Когда редуцированные пали, а ять проявилась в Е, прошла 1 палатализация,формы совпали: брезгать, брезгают - 1 спр. ; чтобы их развести,т.к. значения разные, русская форма ушла, осталась старославянская, глагол из 1 класса перешёл в 4-й, а от исчезнувшего  русского осталась форма 3 лица ( потом был переход нетематических глаголов в тематические), парадигмы перемешались, потому что продуктивные классы влияли на непродуктивные. Получился неправильный, разноспрягаемый глагол.

Лопатин, видимо, решил ошибку убрать: 2 так 2-е, вернул историческую "справедливость". Только кому от этого лучше - не знаю, И так, и так путаться будут. Школьникам,по-моему, легче не будет, многие уже заучили как исключение, так и будем все переучиваться...

Comment: Людмила, брезгать и брезжать - это совсем другие глаголы, с другим значением. Смешения значений произойти не могло, а других причин из тут вспоминать я не вижу. Только запутать все окончательно.  Имхо.
  
А где это Лопатин убрал "ошибку"?

Comment: Так ведь речь не о смешении значений, а о смешении спрягаемых форм от разных глаголов - появились омоформы,я в этих процессах и раньше путалась, сейчас парадигмы не вспомню тем более.Но речь идёт о смешении разных парадигм. Точно так же, как слияние форм бежати и бечи, которые в современном языке слились в один глагол. Форма бегут (З-е л. мн. ч.) — от глагола бечи, остальные — от глагола бежать. В разговорной речи и в некоторых говорах встречаются и древние формы бегит, бегим и т. д.А здесь от брезгти и брезждити - ст.-сл. и русск.

Comment: А брезгать просто повлиял на уход русской словоформы в один из периодов, когда появились омоформы.Потом были другие процессы, формы разошлись, а  закрепился уже старославянизм, от него и 2 спряжение . Но в 3 лице -остаток от парадигмы 1 спр. Вот Лопатин его и убрал (как ошибку)